# Zend: Custom Decorators For Label Tag

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, zend-form

I currently have the following code to generate a form element (text box):

```
$this->addElement('text', 'username', array(
        'label' => 'Username',
        //'multiOptions' => $this->getOptions(),
        'filters' => array(
            'StringTrim',
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array('StringLength', 
                false, 
                array(0, 50)),
        ),
        'decorators' => array(
            array('ViewHelper'), 
            array('Label', array(
                'tag' => 'label',
                'placement' => 'prepend',
                )
            ),
            array('HtmlTag', array(
                'tag' => 'input',
                )
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

This outputs the following in HTML:

```
<dt id="username-label"><label for="username" class="optional">Username</label></dt>
<dd id="username-element">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" class="input"></dd>
```

However, I would expect it to output this:

```
<dt id="username-label"><label for="username" class="**label**">Username</label></dt>
<dd id="username-element">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" class="input"></dd>
```

Why is the label not taking on the label class even though I told it to use the label class in the decorator definition? Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the label class set in the decorator? You've only passed `tag` and `placement` options

Answer (score 0):

Code for rendering a lable of element

**$this->form->name->renderLabel() ;**